# Finding cluster size in c++

Tags: c++

I have the position of `N` points `n` a plane.

`(x(i), y(i))` is the position of point number `i`. I want to know how many clusters are there in the plane and what is the size of each cluster. A cluster is a set of points which are closer than a distance called `r_0`.

For example, if distance between points number `i` and number `j` is less than `r_0`, and distance between point number `j` and point number `k` is also less than `r_0`, all three points are in the same cluster (it is not necessary for distance between point number `i` and `k` to be less than `r_0`)

Could anyone tell me how can I find number and size of clusters if I know `x(i)` and `y(i)` in C++?

Comment: This question might be better suited for Computer Science SE or Math SE.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to divide a set of points into similar groups is part of `data mining`.  There is an algorithm [wikipedia : DBScan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) which does the calculation you need, but requires visiting every node.  In order to decide if it is part of a cluster or not.

### DBScan

Each node is visited, and nearby nodes are checked to see whether they are within a distance delta.  If sufficient nodes are found, then a new cluster is started.  Then the nodes in the cluster are walked to see if they also have any nearby neighbours which belong in the cluster.  When these have been exhausted, a new (untested node), is used.

This is repeated until all the nodes have been visited, and the idea of how many clusters exist is now known.

Answer (score 0):

as you described it, the problem is equivalent to finding the connected components of the graph with vertices the points and edges the r0-closer relation. This will be quadratic in time and linear in space ( or just linear time if you manage to get the edges in O(N) and the avarage number of edges per point is constant ).

A linear in time and quadratic in space solution, could be obtained by writing each point in a boolean matrix in such a way to build the graph in a single pass.

Inbetween solutions could be found by using spatial trees as well ...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However I need an answer

Answer (score 0):

Beware totally untested code:

```
// some coordinates
struct point {
  int x,y;
};
using PointVec = std::vector<point>;

// implicit data structure
struct psetdata {
  point p;
  int parent; // [Disjoint-set data structure][1]

  psetdata(point& p) : p(p), parent(-1) {}
}
using PSet = std::vector<psetdata>;


void Collapse(PSet& pset, PSet::iterator p, int r_0) {
  // reduce the hight of the implicit sets.
  auto q = p;
  auto parent = q->parent;
  while (parent != pset[parent].parent) {
    q->parent = pset[parent].parent;
    q = &pset[parent];
    parent = q->parent;
  }
  p->parent = q->parent; // ultimative parent
}

void Clusters(PointVec& points) {
  PSet pset(points.begin(), points.end());

  for (int idx = 0, auto& p = pset.begin(); p < pset.end(); p++, idx++) {
    if (p.parent == -1)
      p.parent = idx; // my own parent defines a set

    for(auto ptry = p.next(); ptry < pset.end; ptry++) {
      if (dist(p, ptry) < r_0) {
        // ptry to a set.
        Collapse(pset, p);

        if (ptry->parent != -1) {
          Collapse(pset, ptry);
          pset[ptry->parent].parent = p->parent; // merge, need ultimative parent
        }

        ptry->parent = p->parent;
      }
    }
  }

  std::map<int, int> clusters;

  // count clusters
  for (auto p = pset.begin(); p != pset.end(); p++) {
    Collapse(pset, p);

    clusters[p->parent]++;
  }

  // print the sums
  std::cout << "#clusters:" << sets.size() << "\n";
  for (auto& c : clusters) {
    std::cout << c.first << " size " << c.second << "\n";
  }
}


int main() {
  // some sample points
  vector<point> points {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1}};

  Clusters(points, 1);
}
```

Comment: There are lots of errors: clusters.cpp:2:3: error: ‘point’ does not name a type
and so on...

Comment: Sorry, where are (x,y)?

Comment: Could you please add something to make it runable?

Comment: Where is main? I don't know how to run it

Comment: I told you it was totally untested.

Comment: Could you please do me a favor? I have no idea how to use your code. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Updated example.